# Substring function in Jython

Tags: jython, wsadmin

I am using Jython for wsadmin scripting for one of my tasks.

`-c "test = 'project' " +
-c "edit = test[1:]" + 
-c "print edit"`

However when I execute the piece of code , I get the following error

`Traceback (innermost last):
  (no code object) at line 0
  File "<input>", line 1
 edit = test[1:] 
            ¬
SyntaxError: Lexical error at line 1, column 12.  Encountered: "\u00dd" (221),after : ""`

Looks like the square brackets are not being accepted
are there any other ways to obtain  a substring for a string in Jython?

Comment: I have made regular script from your code and it prints `roject` from Jython 2.5.3. Can you run it as regular script? What happens when you change it into one-liner: `test = 'project';edit = test[1:];print edit;`? Can you show us what version of Jython you use?

Comment: I am not sure about the version of Jython but I am using it with WAS 7.0

Answer (score 0):

In Jython slicing works very well and your code in one liner produces `roject` output. I suggest using it as one liner with semicolons instead of line separators:

```
-c "test = 'project';edit = test[1:];print edit;"
```

PS It often helps if you show us your environment: Jython version, OS version etc.

I have tested it on Jython 2.5 and 2.2 and it works:

```
[mn@test ~]# jython -c "import sys; print sys.version; test = 'project';edit = test[1:];print edit;"
2.2.1
roject
```

Comment: Still shows error in same position . I am using Jython for wsadmin in WAS 7.0 running on ZOS

Comment: Can you run Jython as in my edited response and show us results?

Comment: I ran the following `-c "print (sys.version); test='project';edit = test[1:];print edit;"`. but sill the same error `Traceback (innermost last):                                                   
  (no code object) at line 0                                                  
  File "<input>", line 1                                                      
.print (sys.version); test='project';edit = test.1:.;print edit;              
.                                               ¬                             
SyntaxError: Lexical error at line 1, column 48.  Encountered: "\u00dd" (221),`

Comment: One thing I am noticing is that the square bracket is not being recognised by the script processor. Note that in my job log the square brackets are shown as two dots `edit = test.1:.;`

Answer (score 0):

I would try using a script file by using the '-f' switch of wsadmin. It could potentially solve the problem or at least make it much easier to debug. It seems like it might be a character encoding issue judging that \u00dd is a non-standard English character.

See: http://www.charbase.com/00dd-unicode-latin-capital-letter-y-with-acute

Just to be safe, ensure your script file is encoded in UTF-8.